# remove duplicated values of a specific parameter in bash in a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I have a file

```
cat file
ab,12
ab,45
ab,23
bh,32
bl,12
ab,10
bh,13
```

and the file has duplicated lines with the first parameter

I need my output with unique values of a specific parameter separated by comma

For example the output

```
cat file
ab,12
bh,32
bl,12
```

Comment: Do you want just the first occurrence of `ab`? The last? Any arbitrary occurrence? Any of these are relatively easy to do, but you need to provide a more precise specification.

Answer (score 2):

The following command works for your example:

```
sort -u -s -t, -k1,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming OP wants to print first occurrence of the value in `$1`, here is awk one-liner:

```
awk -F"," 'NR==1{print;next} !($1 in a){a[$1]=$0} END{for(i in a) print a[i]}' file
```